# Docker with django issue "no module psycopg2" - but it's installed and in requirements.txt

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I have the issue, that django_api has the error "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'"

psycopg2 is installed ->
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /Users/swestphal/Documents/privateProjects/vue_and_django/ddv/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.8.6)

My requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.3.4
Django==3.2.3
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
djangorestframework==3.12.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2021.1
```

And here my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And here my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  admin_db:
    container_name: django_admin_db
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=django_admin
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/admin_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 33066:3306

  admin_api: 
    container_name: django_api
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - admin_db
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Did you rebuild the images after you added psycopg2 to requirements.txt ?

Comment: Is there any more context to that error message?  Your "it's installed" verification references a path in a host virtual environment; if you `docker run admin_api pip freeze` is it included in the container environment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

but did you install it inside the container ?
command to reinstall from requirements.txt

```
 docker exec admin_api pip install -r requirements.txt
```

adding a line in the requirements.txt doesn't install the package (unless you rebuild the container)

you can also speed it up by just installing the new package :

```
docker exec admin_api pip install <package name>
```

Comment: Any changes you make with `docker exec` will be lost as soon as the container exits.  You should never install software in a container using `docker exec`.

Comment: no it won't if the package is in requirements.txt it will be reinstalled if he rebuilds.
installing software with docker exec is fine when you're coding , anyway it's either that or rebuilding containers which could take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem with postgresql. What you need are linux dev-packages.

Adding this to your dockerfile would help.

```
RUN apt-get update \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  && apt-get install -y build-essential \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apt-get install -y libpq-dev
```